# Using Linq4j with in-memory primitive List and Map

Tags: java, linq4j

I've been trying to search but I can't seem to find some example on how to use `Linq4j` for in-memory data stored in a `java.util.Map`.

Can someone site some links or examples on how to use `Linq4j` for this purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linq4j has good support for working with lists. For example net.hydromatic.linq4j.Linq4j.asEnumerable(List) (and see javadoc http://www.hydromatic.net/linq4j/apidocs/net/hydromatic/linq4j/Linq4j.html for more methods).

```
final List<Employee> employees = Arrays.asList(
    new Employee(100, "Fred", 10),
    new Employee(110, "Bill", 30),
    new Employee(120, "Eric", 10),
    new Employee(130, "Janet", 10));
final List<Employee> result = new ArrayList<Employee>();
Linq4j.asEnumerable(employees)
    .where(
        new Predicate1<Employee>() {
          public boolean apply(Employee e) {
            return e.name.contains("e");
          }
        })
    .into(result);
```

There isn't so much support for Map. You can use the methods on Map that generate collections: Map.keySet(), Map.values() and Map.entrySet(). For example,

```
final List<Grouping<Object, Map.Entry<Employee, Department>>> result =
  new ArrayList<Grouping<Object, Map.Entry<Employee, Department>>>();
Linq4j.asEnumerable(empDepts.entrySet())
    .groupBy(
        new Function1<Map.Entry<Employee, Department>, Object>() {
          public Object apply(Map.Entry<Employee, Department> entry) {
            return entry.getValue();
          }
        })
    .into(result);
```

Lastly, note that there several toMap methods in Enumerable. These are useful for populating maps.

Comment: Also can you give me some insight whether when Linq4j does some query, does it copy the contents of a List or Map into a buffer or of that kind; my concern would be that my persistent map could potentially contain millions of records that it can "iterate" over.

Comment: Originally, I asked this question for an in-memory Map, but the real deal i'm trying to try is the persistent java.util.Map :-)

Comment: Thanks looks neat. I asked this as I was looking for a way to query on the Persistent Map project I have: http://bit.ly/12ii0qO good thing there's a potential way with Linq4j. BTW, it does not use any sort of sun.reflect on it right? I mean, that's just not allowed in the GAE environment in my case...